# Rails Routing Issue with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, mongoid

I have created a action `profile.html.erb` inside users folder where `users` is generated using Devise,

My Route file is,

```
devise_for :users
match '/users/:id', to: 'users#profile', via: :get
```

when i run following paths its working for all

```
http://localhost:3000/users/profile
http://localhost:3000/users/533e40996d696e1279020000
http://localhost:3000/users/533e40996d
```

This is not where i am looking but how to achieve this,

My controller is, '

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def profile
        @user = User.find_by(:id => current_user)
    end
end
```

How to match only current_user id in url path for others it should ask login path or error.

Comment: Its working for all paths http://localhost:3000/users/profile
http://localhost:3000/users/533e40996d696e1279020000
http://localhost:3000/users/533e40996d it should work for only http://localhost:3000/users/533e40996d696e1279020000 path

Comment: I wanted to match current_user id in match '/users/:id', to: 'users#profile', via: :get, so match 'user/:current_user' like this

Comment: Yes i got the answer...